# Android: Getting FATAL exception while launching Activity

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, aop, aspectj

Unable to launch activity. Getting this FATAL AOP exception while launching. This exception started occurring just when I integrated Google analytic to app.

```
08-23 13:32:13.525  12553-12553/in.stocksphere.stocksphere E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.stocksphere.stocksphere, PID: 12553
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.stocksphere.stocksphere/in.stocksphere.stocksphere.ui.CompanyActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to have tried to cast a String cannot be cast to org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint which cannot be done.

Comment: I did not do any ClassCast. I just integrated google analytics as mentioned in their doc.

Comment: The error mentions what I told so I just let you know.

Comment: show us your activities `onCreate` implementation. Somewhere there is a  cast (probably hidden).

Comment: What version do you use to compile the sdk? In build.gradle? if you can help me at another question I posted please tell me the version you used and the logcat shows the error I mentioned.

Comment: I'm not able to post complete code.

Comment: Not the complete code, but an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) including aspect code. Without the code the question will eventually get enough close votes and you will not get your answer. If you want answers, help others to help you by making your problem reproduceable. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)